# How do I change my username?

Tags: permissions, keyrings, user-profile

Some time ago, when I installed Ubuntu, I chose a rather stupid username for my account that I do not want to use anymore.

How do I change this (including the name of my home directory, and the name in the terminal) without losing settings for applications?
How do I keep permissions and my keys for various authentification (e.g. email, SSH, GPG and more)?
What settings could possibly get lost if I changed my username?

Comment: Why can't we navigate to /usr/share/applications/users.desktop >> Click on the user for which the name has to be changed. >> Click on Change User name >> Change the name >> Click on Ok. I think, this would be the easiest way to change the username, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Unix-like operating systems decouple the user name from the user identity, so you may safely change the name without affecting the ID. All permissions, files, etc are tied to your identity (uid), not your username.

To manage every aspect of the user database, you use the `usermod` tool.

To change username and user's groupname (it is probably best to do this without being logged in):

```
sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
sudo groupmod -n newUsername oldUsername
```

This however, doesn't rename the home folder.

To change home-folder, use

```
sudo usermod -d /home/newHomeDir -m newUsername
```

after you changed the username.

For instance, you could logout, drop to a console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), and `sudo su -` to become true root (as opposed to `sudo -s`, where $HOME is still /home/yourname.) Maybe you also have to kill some still running processes from this user first. To do so, enter `ps -u username`, look for the matching PID and kill them by `kill PID-number`.

Update: as arrange mentioned, some files may reference your old home directory. You can either keep a symlink for backward compatibility, e g `ln -s /home/newname /home/oldname` or you can change the file contents with `sed -i.bak 's/*oldname*/*newname*/g' *list of files*` It creates a backup for each file with a .bak extension.

Some additional information for not so experienced users like me:
As I only have ONE user account (administrator), it would not let me change the username ("you are already logged in" was the response in TTY1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). To get around this:

1. Login with your old credentials and add a new user, e.g. "temporary" in TTY1:

   ```
   sudo adduser temporary
   ```

set the password.
2. Allow the temporary user to run sudo by adding the user to sudo group:

```
    sudo adduser temporary sudo
```

3. Log out with the command `exit`.
4. Return to tty1: Login with the 'temporary' user account and password. Change your username and folder as mentioned above. `exit` (until you get the login prompt)
5. Go back to TTY7 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) to login on the GUI/normal desktop screen and see if this works.
6. Delete temporary user and folder:

   ```
   sudo deluser temporary
   sudo rm -r /home/temporary
   ```

Comment: This is unfortunately not true for different configuration files under $HOME, try running something like `grep -IRFl /home/username ~` and you will see how many references to your home directory are stored there.

Comment: I'm running 12.04 LTS on a VirtualBox guest machine. This answer (using the "temporary" account) worked for me. However, the GUI still shows the username as the old username, even after system restart. The terminal prompt and directory structure show the new username. Any idea how to update the username displayed on the GUI?

Comment: Was a simple fix -- Just had to use the User Accounts editor in unity, followed by restart.

Comment: For those with an encrypted home folder, you'll have to edit `/home/.ecryptfs/oldusername/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt` to point to your new home folder,  else you won't be able to login via Unity.

Comment: `sudo usermod -d /home/edge -m edge` yields: `usermod: Directory /home/empedokles could not be renamed in /home/edge` i.e. step 4 won't work.

Comment: I would also recomment `sudo nano /etc/sudoers` and edit/add your new user if zou wany him to sudo

Comment: @JTC *never* edit `sudoers` with plain `nano`. Always use `visudo`.

Comment: I think you can get away without having to make a temporary user if: 1. You log out of the GUI, 2. Login to TTY and `cd /tmp; exec sudo -i`, so that your current shell is *replaced* by the `sudo` process and 3. kill all processes running under your user (`pkill -u $SUDO_USER`). That should eliminate everything that's using your user/home directory.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Kubuntu 16.04, however some things broke. Including the fact that I'm not logged in automatically and xserver won't start automatically either.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04. ``sudo su -``, ``sudo usermod -l new old`` -> ``usermod: user old is currently used by process 123`` where 123 = bash. If you kill it ``kill -9 123``, it exits and goes to login screen. Ie. non-root cannot change their own username.

Comment: To avoid having to delete the home folder of "temporary", create the user using the --no-create-home option

Comment: You would need to change the group as well: sudo groupmod -n new-name current-name

Comment: Why can't we navigate to /usr/share/applications/users.desktop >> Click on the user for which the name has to be changed. >> Click on Change User name >> Change the name >> Click on Ok. I think, this would be the easiest way to change the username, wouldn't it?

Comment: This answer is longer, more confusing, and not linear like the answer from Valentin. While they both have the same basic info, the other is the better answer.

Comment: after usermod for the home folder, the group was still old, so I had to do this: `groupmod -n newGroup oldGroup`

Comment: Why not just create a new user that will have your username and password as you wish: 'sudo adduser urname' and then  add this user to sudo group: 'sudo adduser urname sudo' and then login to that user and delete the old one !?

Comment: Can you do this with ubuntu on wsl?

Comment: is this still the way to go as of ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 157):

To put it all together:

1. Log out of your session or restart your computer to get back to the start screen.
2. At the start screen go to a console mode tty. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (on some Ubuntu revisions this may be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> instead)
3. Log in using your username and password.
4. Set a password for the "root" account.

   ```
    sudo passwd root
   ```
5. Log out.

   ```
    exit
   ```
6. Log in using the "root" account and the password you have previously set.
7. Change the username and the home folder to the new name that you want.

   ```
    usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
    usermod -c "newfullname" <newname>
   ```

   "newfullname" is the fifth column in `/etc/passwd`, and might be "First Last", for instance.
8. Change the group name to the new name that you want.

   ```
    groupmod -n <newgroup> <oldgroup>
   ```
9. Lock the "root" account so it no longer has a valid password that can be used to log in as root.

   ```
    passwd -l root
   ```
10. If you were using ecryptfs (encrypted home directory). Mount your encrypted directory using `ecryptfs-recover-private` and edit `<mountpoint>/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt` to reflect your new home directory.
11. Log out.

    ```
    exit
    ```
12. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the Ubuntu graphics mode login screen (on some Ubuntu revisions this may be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

And now you can log in using your new username.

Comment: If after `usermod -l ` you get a `user <oldname> is currently used by process <processno>`, you can find that process (probably a daemon, or tmux/screen) using `ps aux | grep <processno>`. You might want to gracefully stop that process, otherwise you can `kill <processno>`.

Comment: Thank you for putting this comment together. It was very useful. Two things that might be mentioned though. After step 4 I rebooted so I wouldn't get error messages at step 6. Also, after this process is complete, the /etc/passwd file will have and ID comment matching the old username. This will cause the login screen to display the old login name. I couldn't find a decent way to fix it from the command line, but I did fix it by logging into the user account, going to the account settings and changing the "Login Name" to the username. This updated the /etc/passwd file and fixed the problem.

Comment: This is the most easy and fool-proof way to do it. It's better reboot after step 4 as @Jibbers suggested.

Comment: I'd mention that the "bookmarks in the File browser windows" are now pointing to the old folders, so I have to delete those bookmarks.

Comment: Won't work. If you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 at the beginning it's trying to log in into the newly created user which it won't allow.

Comment: I'm unsure about what locking the root user does (`passwd -l root`), why was that necessary?

Comment: I tried this on Lubuntu 16.04 but it broke my installation: I get cannot loginto lightdm any more, I get a Dialogue "your Display is runnintǵ on low resolution" with a folowup dialog to try the default settings, which are not working, but the other options I cannot reach because there is no mouse to select another option and no possibility to reach the other options with TAB and Arrows.

Comment: I tried this on Lubuntu 16.04 but it **broke my installation**: I cannot log into lightdm any more, I get a Dialogue "The system is running in low-graphics mode" with a followup dialog "try running with the default graphical mode" (which are not working) or "reconfigure graphics" (the other options I cannot choose because there is no mouse pointer to select another option and no possibility to reach the other options with TAB and Arrows!) So: **I had to reinstall lubuntu to get graphics back!**

Comment: You will need to replace any reference in hidden files, and even then some things will still be broken

Comment: Why can't we navigate to /usr/share/applications/users.desktop >> Click on the user for which the name has to be changed. >> Click on Change User name >> Change the name >> Click on Ok. I think, this would be the easiest way to change the username, wouldn't it?

Comment: In My `ubuntu 16.04 LTS`, need to kill all jobs by previous user before step 6 `killall -u <old_user>`, and rename the user directory after step 7 `sudo mv /home/<old_user> /home/<new_user>`

Comment: If doing this over SSH, you need to enable root login in SSHD config for a moment. Go `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config ` uncomment **PermitRootLigin** and change the value to **yes**. Restart SSH `sudo systemctl restart sshd`. After you've modified the user using root, put everything back to how it was ie lock root account and disable remote root login.

Comment: I'm getting Permission denied in step 6 when renaming administrator user account. Any idea how to bypass that?

Comment: for parallels on mac running Ubuntu I had to use `Ctrl-Alt-F3` to get to terminal

Comment: During installation of Ubuntu, setting a username with dots/periods in it was prohibited, so I set the username to `firstlast`. I then followed these instructions *afterwards*, after completing the full Ubuntu installation, to add a period in the username, changing it from `firstlast` to `first.last`, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 32):

Restart in recovery mode and go to the root prompt shell ("Drop to root shell prompt")

First remount the root

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

To change the username and home folder name,

```
usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
```

For group name,

```
groupmod -n <newgroup> <oldgroup>
```

Comment: when I use `usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>` this gives me error `usermod: user oldusername is currently used by process 3170` and if I kill the process still it gives me the same error. using ubuntu 13.10

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS IF YOUR HOME DIRECTORY IS ENCRYPTED!!!! I followed this procedure and it sent me for a wild 2 hour ride... The only way to recover is to perform this procedure again and put the original (disliked) name back in. The problem you will have is "Cannot chdir into mount point"

Comment: Why can't we navigate to /usr/share/applications/users.desktop >> Click on the user for which the name has to be changed. >> Click on Change User name >> Change the name >> Click on Ok. I think, this would be the easiest way to change the username, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04, 16.04:

1. Click on the "System Settings" icon.
2. Click on "User Accounts".
3. Your administrator account should be displayed.
4. Click on the "Unlock" button.
5. Enter your user password as requested to allow changes to your account.
6. Once unlocked, you can click on your old user name that you wish to change and type in a new user name to replace it.
7. When you have typed in the new name, click on the "Lock" button to make the change permanent.
8. Restart Ubuntu.

Comment: This did not change the username for me, just the name. The old username still appears in the terminal, and as the home directory and group (even after rebooting).

Answer (score 3):

When receiving `usermod: can't change /etc/password` just run the following commands:

In the root recovery console run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then rerun:

```
usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
```

Comment: Why can't we navigate to /usr/share/applications/users.desktop >> Click on the user for which the name has to be changed. >> Click on Change User name >> Change the name >> Click on Ok. I think, this would be the easiest way to change the username, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

when you do `usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>` you will get 
`useradd: can't change /etc/passwd` error message to avoid this just add `sudo --` to above command like

```
sudo -- usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
```

and

```
sudo --  groupmod -n <newgroup> <oldgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer listed here by @karthick87 works perfectly fine but here is what I would do just to be safe and avoid all glitches:

1. Create a separate account/user and make sure this account/user root capabilities or login as any root-able user.
2. Logout with the current account and then login with the account mentioned in step 1.
3. Kill all the processes of the previous user.
4. Now follow the steps mentioned by @karthick87 and change username and also the home directory owner.
5. Then follow @Sriraj Hebbar's answer to change the group name.
6. logout with the spare user and login with your user. If you created an extra user delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Since not all the linuces (however *Ubuntu* must have it) have the `usermod` app, there is the way you can do it manually. As of root open **/etc/passwd** to edit with `vim` or any other editor presening in the system:

```
sudo vim /etc/passwd
```

and change the user's name at the beginning of a line:

```
user:x:500:501:username:home/user:/bin/bash
```

to:

```
newuser:x:500:501:username:home/user:/bin/bash
```

then if you worked of root just login, and if you have been logged in as a *user*, logoff, and relogin.

Of course you have to fix **/etc/shadow**, and **/etc/group** also to the system works properly. Thanx to @JohanBoulé

*NOTE*: You should use this approach carefully, to not break the system.

*NOTE*: This approach is common, not only for Ubuntu, but and for ubuntu it will work, however google search will show it event for non ubuntu search, for example for embedded linux

Comment: I tried this way (before I discovered the `usermod` command) and the user's password is no longer accepted.

Comment: @BenVoigt not all the pcs have the usermod

Comment: It's Ubuntu!  If it doesn't have `usermod` your install is broken as it is part of the `passwd` package, which is **required**.

Comment: @Auspex I know that here is the ubuntu QA, but this approach is common, not only for ubuntu, but and for ubuntu it will work, however google search will show it event for non ubuntu search, for example for embedded linux

Comment: I also do it this way regardless of whether usermod or whatever pseudo magical obscure opaque command exists because I find it simpler to remember, and it doesn't bug me with running processes. You need to edit /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow at the minimum, and also /etc/group if you want to have a group with the same name as the user.

Comment: @JohanBoulé thanx

Comment: I had intended to leave this but I can't. First this is the Ubuntu Q&A as you admit. Suggesting a method that is not required on an Ubuntu system and **is potentially dangerous** is a bad idea. @JohanBoulé 's argument is very bad. This "pseudo magical obscure opaque command" exists to make this sort of change easy _without_ making it possible to break logins, as Ben managed to do. `usermod` is not magic, it's not obscure, and it is the **correct** way to make the change on Ubuntu.

Comment: My very bad argument, as you said, is that the fileformats of passwd, shadow, and groups, are dead-simple and fairly well documented and standard ... and easy to remember or lookup in the manpages.
Also notice that the groupmod command is *not* going to do for you all the edits that are needed in the group file. So, for the group file, go on and open it with your favorite text editor to replace *all* the occurrences of "debian".
Finally, notice that the provided workarounds to running processes cannot be used on headless servers that disallows root ssh login, which the default.

Comment: @Auspex " it is the correct way to make the change on Ubuntu. " that isn't unique method, people have to know ALL the methods, I've already assertained in it here on SO/SE

Comment: This is not SO/SE. This is AskUbuntu

Comment: @Auspex hah, didn't you really know that AskUbunty is undeed a member of SO/SE community?)

Comment: Of course I know that. And there's nothing wrong with adding an alternate answer in AskUbuntu, but the pure fact is that this IS AskUbuntu, and if you'd prefaced it with "For non-Ubuntu systems you might want to use...", I'd be fine with it. However, Ubuntu systems **must** have `usermod`, and `usermod` is the correct way to do this on an Ubuntu system. **Ubuntu** users do _not_ have to be told methods that can break their systems. And suggesting `vim` is equally wrong...

Comment: @Auspex for me, (im using ALT) i prefer always way to fix username manually with editor, even **usermod** is also present  on my system, so that is the only additional correct way to change username along with usermod one. And this method itself can't bear the system, because system can be broken by a human...  Some changes I did