# Changing my Home folder's owner

Tags: 11.04, permissions, home-directory

I recently updated my ubuntu to 11.04 and have run into an issue. I decided to do a fresh install instead of an upgrade and made my username different from my last. Now everything has my past usernames permissions.

How can I transition my home folder into my new installation/username.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a pretty good question and I imagine a lot of people run into this same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Well as far home folder goes

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER`

will do  the trick I think.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the [user name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) is not so trivial in Ubuntu.

It would therefore be best advice to create a new user with you previous user name. To do so open *System Settings -> Users and Groups*. From *-> Advanced Settings* we may define the location of our `/home/<username>/` directory. Choose the path to your old `/home/username` and you are done:

[image]