# How to reset main user account?

Tags: gnome

My main account got messed up, as I tried to fix it things went downhills.

- keyboard mess - tried unity --restore and deleting .gconf2*, fail
- deleted .* in ~, total havoc. Chromium and Firefox crashes etc.

Now, another user account is fully functioning, but I really want my regular username back.

Is there any way to completely wipe the settings for the messed up account or copy the profile from the functioning user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would boot into recovery mode an go to the root shell, then do:

Backup old folder:

```
mv /home/youruser /home/youruser-backup
```

Create new 'home' folder for youruser

```
mkdir /home/youruser
```

Set correct read/write access

```
chown youruser:youruser /home/youruser
```

Reboot system

```
shutdown -r now
```

That would give you an empty folder for your old default user. You should be able to login and then copy your important files back from youruser-backup to youruser.

Comment: If you dont feel like booting up (twice) and entering recovery mode you can create a temp user with admin privileges (using GUI: `Administration > Users and Groups`), logout and login with this user, and then issue the above commands. Logout and youre ready to login with your "reseted" original user :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your old non-working user account, then rename the new working account to the old username, see this question: [How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)

Comment: Would the new user be in the sudoers group?