# top bar items misplaced needs help

Tags: gnome, 20.04, top-bar

Ubnutu 20.04 & gnome 3.36

I installed new ubuntu and tried some gnome extensions but now my top bar items are at wrong positions even after multiple reboots and uninstalling all the extensions. I really don't want to reinstall ubuntu for this bug.

[image]

Comment: Indicate in your answer what extensions you installed in a chance to attract more specific answers. If all fails, reset your user account https://askubuntu.com/questions/43584/how-to-reset-main-user-account

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the command suggested by Christoph didn't help. I started fiddling with my GNOME settings in GNOME Tweaks and found the culprit to be the Paper icon theme. Switching to another icon theme followed by moving the mouse over the misplaced icons fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Interesting! From the screenshot provided in the question, it seems the OP is also using the Paper icon theme. This might be the right answer after all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue after upgrade to 20.04
Executing the following command to reset gnome settings worked for me. Misplaced items in top bar are now corrected.

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome
```