# GNOME Preferences and Settings are not getting saved

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-control-center

I updated my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS today. All my preferences and settings got reset. From GNOME Settings, I am unable to retain my changes. Say, I want to enable touchpad click, the settings are not retained after closing the window. Similar is the case for gnome-terminal, where my custom default profile is not retained. When I restart the terminal, it again comes back to the previous setting (white terminal and small font of 10).

How can I maintain my GNOME settings? I could not find a proper solution to this problem. A few ideas I read were

1. to remove `~/.config/dconf/` and relogin.
2. change the user permission using `chown`.

But nothing worked. Please let me know the fix to this problem.

Comment: Try resetting your user account: https://askubuntu.com/questions/43584/how-to-reset-main-user-account

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply it didn't work out to reset the main user account. I found a partial solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934641/glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend-your-settings-will-not-b. Due to this, I am able to save my gnome-terminal preferences. But `gnome-control-center` problem still exists. I am able to change the settings but they are not getting reflected. For example, "Tap to click" is getting saved but does work.