# How to soft reset Ubuntu?

Tags: reset

I recently downloaded Ubuntu, and I was new to it. Now that I have more knowledge I would like to reset it and make it my own.

Comment: The only way to 'reset' Ubuntu is to reinstall it.

Comment: You can re-install and have it reset packages (install to existing partitions without format and it'll cause system directories to get erased; then install new system and [*auto*] add back your additional packages you had installed) - but user configs in user directories are not touched; so your changes (*even mistakes*) will survive that. It will however fix most package issues (*given system directories were wiped prior to install; packages will be new*). What is you want to reset?  if it's a user-config that won't be touched by this type of install....

Comment: I have many Lubuntu installs (*at least one for each supported release*) I do *strange* & *stupid* things to for support purposes (*answering questions here & elsewhere*).  I don't worry about what packages mistakes I make (*repeating users errors for example to get their broken-state*) as I know I can re-install & fix almost all user issues; but my wanted packages (*music player which isn't a default player for Lubuntu, my music on the box*) are not touched via the install process I'm referring to.  It's the means I use to *upgrade* packages on boxes too (a Lubuntu QA-testcase install)

Comment: I am voting to close this because what is meant by "soft reset" is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configuration at the system level, that can only be changed by users with root permissions.

Then you have per user configuration. That configuration resides in the user's home directory under hidden folders and files, i.e., of which the name starts with a .dot.

**Reset user configuration**

As a beginning user, you may not have fundamentally changed system wide configuration. It therefore is sufficient to reset your account, or parts of it.

- To reset every setting related to the standard Ubuntu desktop, you can use the command `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`.
- You can also more thoroughly [reset your entire Ubuntu account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43584/how-to-reset-main-user-account).

**Reset entire system**

- Reinstall the operating system, erasing the previous install.

Changes at the system level are not as such logged. There is therefore no way to automatically roll back in a default Ubuntu install - you have to know what you did and undo it yourself. To have a fully pristine system, a reinstall is the only option. That, however, typically does not take more than an hour.