# How to rename a user safely?

Tags: users, user-profile, username

I've misspelled user name when installing Ubuntu and would like to rename if possible. How can I safely change my user name?

Comment: [This answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/34074/3940) may still be valid.

Comment: @takkat thanks. There you've got a good formal answer on how to rename a user. But I believe Jo-Erlend's suggestion I've got here is safer :-)

Comment: If you haven't done much with your user, I'd definitely go for Jo-Erlends approach. I had other people in mind that may come here for a more sophisticated solution on this topic. Renaming users is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safely? Don't rename at all. Instead, (make sure the user is logged out first) create a new user with the correct username, rename the old home directory to the new username and chown -R the folder to the new user.

This assumes that you're not using encrypted homes. That would require some different steps, but since I haven't done that myself, I'll leave that to someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Use `usermod` like so:

```
usermod -l newname currentname
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faces such problem and got working solution.

1. Make backup of the users- and groups-related files

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/passwd ~/passwd.bak
   sudo cp /etc/group ~/group.bak
   sudo cp /etc/subuid ~/subuid.bak
   sudo cp /etc/subgid ~/subgid.bak
   sudo cp /etc/gshadow ~/gshadow.bak
   sudo cp /etc/shadow ~/shadow.bak
   ```
2. We need to boot in *Recovery mode* (click <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot, in GRUB select *Advanced options for Ubuntu*, select *Ubuntu, with Linux ... (recovery mode)*)
3. Select `root    Drop to root shell prompt` to access root-shell
4. Enter your main user (usually GID = 1000, member of sudo group) password here when asked

   ```
   Press Enter for maintenance
   (or press Control-D to continue):
   ```
5. Remount all filesystems with read and write

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   mount -o rw,remount /home
   ```
6. Rename user from  *old_user* to *new_user*, rename comment on user-name (field 5 in `/etc/passwd`) and move its home

   ```
   OLDNAME="old_user"
   NEWNAME="new_user"
   usermod -l $NEWNAME $OLDNAME -c $NEWNAME -d /home/$NEWNAME  -m
   ```
7. Rename user's group from *old_user* to *new_user*

   ```
   groupmod $OLDNAME -n $NEWNAME
   ```
8. Replace *old_user* to *new_user* in `/etc/subgid` and `/etc/subuid`

   ```
   sed -i "s/$OLDNAME/$NEWNAME/g" /etc/subuid
   sed -i "s/$OLDNAME/$NEWNAME/g" /etc/subgid
   ```
9. Reboot the system and then login with *new_user* name and old password. Optionally change password with `passwd`
10. If goes right - remove backed-up files:

    ```
    sudo rm ~/passwd.bak ~/group.bak ~/subuid.bak ~/subgid.bak \
    ~/gshadow.bak ~/shadow.bak
    ```

Note: you can read about used options of `usermod` and `groupmod` on their man-pages.