# How to change a user ID safely if you are using encrypted home?

Tags: permissions, files, encryption, users, home-directory

Inspired [by this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68298/how-to-rename-a-user-safely), that seems to imply that a simple `chown` won't work because you won't be able to access the encrypted files. So how is the safest but still simple workaround?

Comment: I ran into this and got tired of messing with it and seeing as it was a new install with only a few files to backup and a bunch of stuff to reinstall it seemed easier to just reinstall. This should definitely be made easier.