# Changed username. Now I cannot log on or view my previous files

Tags: username

I want to change my username and followed the instructions from [How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) by creating a temp user with admin privileges. While logged in as temp, I did :

```
sudo usermod -l newname oldname
sudo usermod -d /home/newname -m newname
```

Now I cannot log in under `newname` and `/home` only lists `newname` and `temp`

Reading through other sites now, it seems I should have used

```
usermod -d /home/newname -m oldname
```

Based on this, I think I may have deleted the contents of my previous home folder??

I'm sure I'm not the first person to do some stupid while changing username, but any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Log in as temp again, open a terminal and type

```
sudo passwd newname
```

No, I don't think you have removed your old user, the -m option should move the home to newname.