# Change user name

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)

> Recently i've added new accounts in my PC, and for one of those need to
>   change name:
>   I've try to change it by "graphical procedure" from "account manager menu"
>   but change only the name in LogIn screen and near the clock.
>   If I open a Terminal the name remain the old one.
>
> I need to have this situation
>   from Old name: franco@PC-Casa:~$ -----> I want obtain New name:
>   francesco@PC-Casa:~$ o
>
> How i can do this without create a new one user and transfer all data?
>   Can you explain me step by step the procedure?

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username