# Accidentaly deleted contents of the home folder

Tags: home-directory, restore

so, I wanted to rename the user and its corresponding home folder following the instructions mentioned here [How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username). However, what this made me is to rename the account, not the folder, and apparently I deleted all the contents of the home folder! Now I am also not able to log into the account through the ubuntu 11.04 desktop version and frankly I am a bit lost on how to solve this issue cause I do have a valuable data in the home folder.

ls -la of the folder:

```
dr-x------ 3 sheldon sheldon 4096 Mar  5 12:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root    4096 Mar  5 12:04 ..
-rw------- 1 root    root    2013 Mar  4 17:44 .bash_history
```

Any ideas? How can I restore everything as it was and get my data back?

Thanks a milion!

Comment: What do you mean by "`ls -la` of the folder"? What folder? `/home`? If you deleted your user folder, the data is gone, unless you want to dive into data recovery but that might be a bit over your head if your Linux skills are only elementary.

Answer (score 0):

If all that you've done is rename the account, the home folder may still be there under `/home/oldusername/`.

To check this, open a terminal and enter `sudo ls -al /home/oldusername/`.

If you see your 'lost' files, enter `sudo cp -r /home/oldusername/* /home/newusername/`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a recovery for your deleted files. I advise you to use R-studio for Linux which is a free version of R-studio data recovery tools.

R-Studio for Linux recovers files:

- Deleted from the computer and emptied from the Trash
- Corrupted due to a virus, power failure or sudden shutdown
- From disks that have been Re-formatted to the same file system or a
  different file system
- Damaged and have bad sectors-R-Studio for Linux creates an image of
  the entire disk and recovers it from there to prevent further
  physical damage to the disk

You can download from [here](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/Download.shtml).