# Renaming user name

Tags: users, user-management, user-profile

I made a mistake in the username at the time of installation. So I changed the name of the user after logging in by creating a guest account with SUDO rights. But when I checked the list of users using ls /home command I am not seeing the new name for the user instead Old name is appearing. But I use the new name to login.

Is it like I need to change the name inside Home directory separately? Also , if there is any other changes needs to be done .. ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username/317008 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98461/proper-way-of-changing-username-in-ubuntu-or-any-linux

Answer (score 107):

Procedure  to  rename or  change username in Ubuntu:

If running as the user to be modified, logout first, 
then open a console:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Otherwise, simply open a new Terminal:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And run:

```
exec sudo -i
killall -u [oldname]
id [oldname]
usermod -l [newname] [oldname]
groupmod -n [newname] [oldname]
usermod -d /home/[newname] -m [newname]
usermod -c "[full name (new)]" [newname]
id [newname]
```

Example:

```
sudo -i
killall -u belaje
id belaje
uid=1000(belaje) gid=1000(belaje) groups=1000(belaje),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),127(sambashare)
usermod -l  balaja belaje
groupmod -n balaja belaje
usermod -d /home/balaja -m  balaja
usermod -c "Bala Jagannathan" balaja
id balaja
```

Whenever you want to get back from console version to graphical version:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Using this procedure I successfully modified user account however only from another account (which I had to create for that purpose and later deleted). I wonder if that is the case (which is not mentioned actually) or I was doing something wrong?
The main point was that "killall -u oldname" logged me out so that I couldn't continue remaining steps.

Comment: This probably would be better done through a TTY, not a terminal emulator in GUI. So I'd replace the keyboard shortcut to terminal emulator with shortcut to TTY1, which is Ctrl + Alt + F1

Comment: Please add that if the user has an encrypted home directory, it's also necessary to edit `/home/newname/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt` to point to the new home directory.

Comment: Does not really work for me. After doing this, the ui does not work properly anymore. After login it just shows the desktop wallpaper.

Comment: Instead of `killall` and `usermod` (which I didn't want to do through an SSH connection with the logged-in user) I had success with changing the user name in `/etc/passwd` **and** `/etc/shadow` .

Comment: As baltascejas tried to point out:  pressing `Ctrl-Alt-T` while logged in as the user you are trying to edit will just kill your session when you `killall -u oldname`

Comment: should this line: `usermod -d /home/newname -m newname` be this instead: `usermod -d /home/oldname -m newname` (note the change from old name to new name)??

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Nope. After renaming the account, the new login is using the `/home/oldname` folder. You specify the new folder name and the user it's for, so `newname` both times. https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod

Comment: why exec? is it really needed?

Comment: In WSL `killall` didn't work, as a new process started shortly after `killall`. So i ran: `killall -u [oldname] && usermod -l [newname] [oldname]`

Answer (score 22):

on the server this worked for me:

```
sudo usermod -md /home/NewHome -l NewName OldName
sudo groupmod -n NewGroupName OldGroupName
```

This renames the user and its group and also the home folder.

Answer (score 3):

This works, but a lot of the apps will break because they specifically call for the `/home/oldusername`; many individual software authors don't use variables to call their configs, they directly specify oldusername not $HOME. Chrome, GTK and firefox break like this. Don't forget your keyrings will have the old credentials as well... I'm not sure how to back those up.... maybe export them?

So, I end up doing the following to change username - man i wish i knew an easier way.

- as `olduser`, sign in to chrome and firefox to sync out the settings
- using users and groups in Settings, create user `killmenow` with pass of same, make him admin, reboot and log in as `killmenow`.
- open terminal, riun `sudo i`, then `mkdir /home/newusername` and making it the same uid:gid as the `oldusername`
- Move usercreatedfiles.xyz, Desktop, Downloads, and other dirs containing created files like docs, pics, music, movies, etc in `/home/oldusername/` to `/home/newusername`.
- Find out any specific apps with particular settings...
  Helpful to pay attention here :) user will likely bean you with a phonebook if you lose their files ;)
- `vi /etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to reference `newusername` and `/home/newusername`
- `passwd newusername` and enter a temporary password twice
  reboot and log in as `newusername`, password  being what you entered in the previous point.
- delete `killmenow` using "users and groups" in Settings.

wait until some time passes before deleting `/home/oldusername`  - in case you missed important stuff... or move it to `/home/newusername/Downloads` and  tell them

```
mv /home/oldusername /home/newusername/Downloads/oldusername-backup
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try the below to change the user name in home directory,

```
usermod -d /home/newHomeDir -m newUsername
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Tried the above but no luck .. Here's what I'm getting

Comment: After doing the above logout your machine and try login again.