# Fixing links on sidebar of file explorer after changing username

Tags: username

I changed ***my username and home directory*** as described in this [ask-ubuntu-link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username). However, now I can not access many items on sidebar (Documents, music, pictures) by clicking because the link is associated with my old user id while folders' names have been changed.

Could someone please help me?

UPDATE:

My old username was: `kumar` and new one is: `dkumar`. I can access `/home/dkumar/Documents` by typing it in nautilus. But, link on `sidebar` of explorer is still showing `/home/kumar/Documents` and hence, when I click there, I get the error message that "`Could not find /home/kumar/Documents . Please check the spelling and try again`"

Comment: by saying explorer, do you mean Nautilus?

Comment: @PauliusŠukys Yah, you are right. Since I am new to Ubuntu, I still do not proper terminology. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(edited in 2020 for current versions of Ubuntu)**

Edit the file `/home/dkumar/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` manually and correct the wrong paths.

Then, restart nautilus: `nautilus -q`.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely the problem you're facing is not being the file/directory owner.
You can check this by executing `ls -al` on your `/home/username` directory to see who the owner is.

To fix this problem just by using [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) (check the examples section)

```
chown -hR username /home/username
```

Comment: chown command did not help. Please see the update to my original question.