# change username in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, username

when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 I missed some thing on my user name , how to correct it and display it correctly in the terminal.

thanks for help .

Comment: Missed what? You'd probably have to create a new user account.

Comment: I missed a letter ,  just i want to change it !

Comment: `useradd YOURNAMEHEE` follow the prompts `cp -R ~/* ../YOURNAMEHERE` `userdel YOUROLDACCOUNTHERE`

Comment: no need to create new user, see my answer

Comment: I found save way to change my user name here 

[http://askubuntu.com/a/34075/423340][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/34075/423340

Answer (score 1):

Do following from root or user with sudo rights:

`sudo usermod -l new_username current_username`

`sudo mv /home/current_username /home/new_username`

`sudo usermod -d /home/new_username new_username`

And optional, but not sufficient (I think usermod should change only login name, but not your UID)

`sudo chown -R new_username /home/new_username`

I believe it will be enough for changing user name. Please note, never do that from current user name!!! Log in as root or another user with sudo rights.

See good article on Arch Linux wiki (applicable to all common Linux distros)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_username

Comment: ask me if you have any problems

Comment: After a fresh install this is not needed. My solution will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit user name.

You can create another user with correct name with administrative privileges. Then login with new user account and remove the incorrect user.

It can be done from System Settings -> User Accounts application.

Comment: That's not true. User login, home, group can be simply changed if user have access to root or user account with root rights.

Comment: @user3417815 I know. But it is not straight forward to change user name and home directory, etc for a newbie.

Comment: maybe, but we can post simple set of command for this and let know user what is possible to do in any way (gui and cli)

Comment: @user3417815 I marked it as duplicate. There is a ready answer.

Comment: yeah, so common question.  of course user should search before ask something.