# Change root username

Tags: 12.04, root

Beginner user here.

I want to change root username to something else?
Is that possible, and if yes - how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Security. It's a well know login username, and wanted to change it into something more complex.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that does not work in Linux. What I would suggest is to edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and set `PermitRootLogin no` to prevent anyone from logging in as root. If this is a server you should also disable Password Authentication and use Public Keys instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my username?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but not recommended. The username `root` is not magical. The fact that it has a `UID` of 0 is what gives `root` its power. Tools like `/bin/ls` that translate between the `UID` value in a file's inode and a name (unless you `/bin/ls -n`) use the `password database` (See `man nss;man nsswitch.conf`) to do the translation. The `getent` command fetches entries:

```
 $ getent passwd root  
 root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

(See `man 5 passwd;man shadow` for info about the contents.)

So, you **could** edit `/etc/passwd`, find the line with the `UID` of zero, and change the user name of `root` to some other value.

What do you suppose you have gained? Do you know of any program dumb enough to check for `$USERNAME = "root" rather than`$UID = 0`? The system sure doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. In Windows, you can have guests and admins. In Ubuntu, there are guests, admins and the root. And nobody can actually BE the root, only use root powers. So no, there is no way to change the root's name.