# How do you export/move your home directory to another user?

Tags: 14.04

Let's say I have 2 account, account A & B. I don't want to use account A anymore, yet I still want to retain all the files. I want to move account A's belongings to account B. How do I do that?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username

Comment: Why do you need a different account?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the user account change?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about already existing application settings of account B, you can copy the contents of `/home/accounta` with all hidden files and overwrite everything in `/home/accountb`, I guess. You can simply do that in a terminal: `sudo cp -R /home/accounta/* /home/accountb/`.

Else you'd have to sort everything by hand. I'd recommend to create a new folder in Account A (While being logged into Account A) and moving everything you need there. To see hidden files in Nautilus go to (no free translating) `Edit`→`Settings`→`[ ] Show hidden files and backups` and tick it. Then move it as above: `sudo cp -R /home/accounta/new\ folder/* /home/accountb/`.

Lastly, I think, you will have to take care of some file ownerships. I think that can be done only by executing `sudo chown -R accountb /home/accountb && sudo chgroup -R accountb /home/accountb`.

**DISCLAIMER:** I didn't look up any of this. To be sure, at least try every command without `sudo` and look for syntax errors etc.!