# Changed user name in CLI. But even after rebooting, user name is the same

Tags: command-line, user-management, username

Changed user name in CLI. But even after rebooting,user name is the same in GUI. Why it didn't get changed..? Shall we try to change in GUI mode itself? The users are common to both CLI and GUI right?

Comment: Which method did you use to change the username?

Comment: @Wilf : I used 'usermod -l newuser olduser'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort of have two usernames - a username that is usable in SSH, TTYs etc, and the full-name that shows on the login screen - you should be able to see this in your relevant line in `/etc/passwd` - for example:

```
wilff:x:1001:1001:Random:/home/wilff:/bin/bash
```

So in my above case, my username for logging in via SSH/TTY etc is `wilff` (this is also used for the name of the home directory), whereas my full-name is currently `Random`.

## To change the full-name

You can change the full-name via this command:

```
sudo chfn -f <NEW-FULL-NAME> <username>
```

or this one:

```
sudo usermod -c <NEW-FULL-NAME> <username>
```

Where `<NEW-FULL-NAME>`is the new full-name and `<username>` is the

So, for example again - command:

```
sudo usermod -c Magic wilff
```

resulting line in `/etc/passwd`:

```
wilff:x:1001:1001:Magic:/home/wilff:/bin/bash
```

This should also be possible via the User Settings in most Desktop Environments.

## To change your username

<sup>Guessing this is the bit you have already done</sup>

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username).