# how to remove usr/lib/java/jdk/1.8.0_45

Tags: java, jdk

I can't recall what I did wrong but i have a folder named "usr/lib/java/jdk/1.8.0_45"
that has a desktop for itself in it and all that, basicly an user for itself and all my pictures get saved in there and sometimes it messes with my downloads but I can't remove it in system settings/users. So could somebody please help me on removing it.

Comment: Am I right in thinking all your asking is how to remove this folder ?

Comment: I don't know what it has a user format for itself. That's just Java Dev Kit's lib folder. Do you want to delete the folder completely?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the folder completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/java/jdk/1.8.0_45
```

`-r` will delete files with the directory itself.

Comment: @A.B. he said he wanted to  delete folder .../1.8.0_45, no need to edit the directory

Comment: says that there is no such file or directory, but there is for example when i open gimp

Comment: @robibaricevic the editor changed the directory while editing the answer, try again, i corrected it

Comment: @biozalp edit? I haven't edited the folder.

Comment: @A.B. you have written 1.9.0_45 instead of 1.8.0_45, i corrected it again

Comment: now it just says that it can't be deleted because the directory is not empty

Comment: use `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/java/jdk/1.8.0_45` ?

Comment: ok, thank you now for the last thing do you know how to change my terminal director( I don't know if that term is right), but before it used to be just my user name and home I think and now it's this"robi@robi-SATELLITE-L50-B:/home/robi$ "

Comment: @biozalp read the change history http://askubuntu.com/posts/695491/revisions

Comment: @A.B. ok, my bad

Comment: @robibaricevic http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username this link might help maybe, i dunno how that happened, open up a new question of that maybe?

Comment: @robibaricevic and can you approve my answer if that worked in order to people see the solution of possible upcoming errors of other users?

Answer (score 0):

If, based on your comment, all you want is that folder removed then, one simple command in a terminal

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/java/jdk/1.8.0_45
```

If the issue is deeper than that, you say it has its own user ???, first find the exact name of the user you want removed user like this

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

Then remove it like this

```
sudo userdel username
```

Changing `username` for the user you want gone.