# Renamed home folder, now I can't log in

Tags: data-recovery, password-recovery

I'm new to Ubuntu, and this is my first post on this site.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. I was trying to change the name of my home folder. I right clicked the folder but the "Rename" option was grayed out. So I selected "Log in as administrator" (or something along those lines). Then I was able to rename the folder. After I renamed it, I got a warning that the file couldn't be located. In other words when I click on "Places" and "Home" or "Desktop" I get a warning that it cannot be found or opened. I re started the computer, thinking that will fix it. But now I get a log in screen that I have never had before all this, and it isn't accepting my password. 
How do I log in, or at the very least recover my files?

Comment: Why would you rename your home folder?

Comment: I didn't like the name I had given it when I first installed Ubuntu.

Comment: That isn't how you change your username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of a live CD may not be necessary. The following was not tested, but should work.

Try to switch to text-only mode in your login promt by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and try to login. After the correct password, you should receive a message, that you can not change the directory to your home directory and `$HOME` is set to `/`.

Afterwards, you are able to rename your home folder to the original name.
Alternatively, you can change the location of your home directory in `/etc/passwd`, **but you should be sure what to change.**

Comment: If the OP changed their home folder name thinking it would change their username, they probably don't know how to rename folders from the terminal. This is a good plan if there is no possibility of a LiveCD, but clearer instructions would be better :).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use a LiveDVD/USB to fix this. If you have another computer, download a copy of Ubuntu and burn it to your media of choice. Boot from that LiveMedia on the broken computer. Don't choose install when prompted, choose "Try before installing." You should be greeted with an Ubuntu desktop after some time. Open the file browser, open your hard drive, go to `/home/`, and rename your user folder back to its original name.

You said in a comment that you don't like your username, and that's why you renamed the folder. That isn't how it works. [Read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) for info on how to change your username.

If you need further help, just comment :).