# Nautilus not opening folders and ntfs disks

Tags: nautilus

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, had to delete my olduser and created a new one following the steps on this answer [How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username), used the command usermod and changed the username and home directory but now nautilus refuses to open my folders and disks:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

I already rebooted the system and no luck, can't find anything on the internet about this error.

The first image displays the message "Couldn't show <> the file type is not recognized" or something similar.

The second image displays the message "Something went wrong, the requested file couldn't be found. Check that is correctly spelled and try agai"

It's not the exact translation but i didn't find anything on google with that error.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Translate those messages to English, please.

Comment: If you open a terminal and type sudo nautilus, then try to open a folder, what error message is displayed? It could be a permissions problem?

Comment: It says this on the terminal:

dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot connect: Connection refused

Comment: May sound obvious, but have you tried creating a new user account using in Settings/User Accounts, logging into that new account, do you have the same issue?

Comment: I didn't tried it out :D gonna test. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, indeed with another user works perfect, but with mine it doesn't, how can i solve it?

Comment: I would suggest using the new profile and move all your files and configs over to the new user. That would be the easiest solution. I had a problem with a profile and moving everything was easy....

Comment: If you wanted to try resetting your profile here is some info (but I would suggest just moving your data to your new user account, you could back up externally, move everything to the new account, then delete the original account, recreate another new user with the same name as the original and move all files back. Remember do a system backup before resetting your profile, just in case.) LINK: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1105433

Answer (score 0):

Try to revert the Nautilus file manager to the default configuration/settings via command line interface.

All you have to do is to delete the ~/.config/nautilus and ~/.config/nautilus_old files.

In this article I will rename them so that it can be restored if something goes wrong:

```
mv ~/.config/nautilus ~/.config/nautilus_old

mv ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus_old
```

Reboot. If you are happy with the default configurations, delete the configuration files we have just renamed:

```
rm -r ~/.config/nautilus_old

rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus_old
```

I would suggest using synaptic package manager to reinstall Nautilus and Nautilus-Data

Comment: Thanks but not working, already did that and stills gives me the error "The file if from an unknown file type"