# How do i figure out the user name on a laptop I bought

Tags: grub2

I changed the password but I don't know how to do the username

Comment: You might be better off doing a clean install if you just bought the system. http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username

Comment: It seems like you're asking [how to change your username](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username), rather than just how to find out what it is. However, if you're *not* trying to change your username, or if that linked question doesn't seem to be what you need, then please [edit] your question with details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, and then use a command like "id", "whoami", or even "ls /home/" should do on a fresh install.