# Need help fixing broken nautilus directory links on launcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, directory, home-directory

I accidentally made a spelling mistake while creating the user during installation of Ubuntu 16.04. I had to rename my username and home folder later (I did something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)). Now, the Nautilus icon takes me to the new home folder alright but other links like Downloads, Documents etc within the home folder seems broken.

[image: Links]

And I get the following error message:

[image: Error]

I checked the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file whose contents were as follows:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

This looked proper and I went and checked the `$HOME` variable in terminal as below:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~$ eval echo $HOME
/home/user4
```

This clearly is fine. I tried `xdg-user-dirs-update` and also a reboot. Still the links are broken. How can I fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by actually fixing broken `nautilus` links. I realized that these links are nothing but the same bookmarks on the left pane of your file manager. All I had to do was:

```
sudo gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

This opens the configuration file and you could edit the links by following the format below:

```
file://<full_path> <bookmark_name>
```

for directories and

```
smb://<IPv4_address>/<shared_directory_name>
```

for shared folders on network (using `samba`).

That's it! You may even add other bookmarks by specifying the paths here.

Another (easier) alternative for broken paths (works only for folders created by user) is:

1. Right click on the directory name left pane of bookmarks.
2. Click `Remove`.
3. Navigate to the path of the directory using the file manager (`nautilus`).
4. Hover to `Bookmarks` menu, click and select `Add Bookmark`.

More info can be found [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/193777/beginner-how-to-add-a-bookmark-to-a-location-in-nautilus-files-in-ubuntu-14.04/) and [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/adding-bookmarks-folders-nautilus-sidebar-ubuntu-12-04).