# Wifi list not showing (but can connect) and desktop behaving oddly after changing username with usermod

Tags: wireless, lock-screen, username

So I changed my Ubuntu's username and after that the list of wifi is showing sometimes and sometimes not but the laptop is connecting to the wifi, and it shows the symbol shown when it gets connected to ethernet.

Also after changing the username, whenever I restart my computer, the lock screen does not show the desktop wallpaper but shows the purple screen. However after logging in once, and then logging out, it shows the wallpaper normally.

[image: Connected icon of ethernet. List of wifi not shown.]

I did the following steps:

```
sudo passwd root
usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
groupmod -n <newgroup> <oldgroup>
```

If this doesn't move the home folder, then I moved the home folder too to be over the new name.

UPDATE: There is some more weird behaviour. So consider a wifi network with name iitk. I connect to it. Then I go somewhere with the same wifi network, and it connects. And in connections, it shows one as iitk1, one as iitk2. Why? It didn't do that before.

The problems are not anything major but they are very irksome. So if anyone can provide a solution, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Run `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Comment: what do you mean by you changed Ubuntu's username? Did you change your username or your hostname? How did you do that?

Comment: Zanna: Changed it in this way: https://askubuntu.com/a/317008/678350
M.Becerra: Did it and it is still connecting to the wifi but not showing the list of wifi or which wifi it is connected to
DavidFoerster: All of these problems started after a single operation so I thought it would all be linked?

Comment: I voted the question as unclear not too broad - I think you were right to include both problems as they seemed to have the same cause. I am not sure I understand fully - did you set the root password as well? Please could you edit your question and include all the commands you used?

Comment: I did not have root password so I set it too. Then changed the username

Comment: Hmm what do you mean about moving the home folder? How did you do that? What's the full path of your new home directory? Open a terminal and execute `pwd` if unsure... (By the way, Ubuntu disables the root account by not setting a password for it - you did not need to do that and it is not recommended. But that would not cause the problems you are seeing.)

Comment: I would grep for your old username in the new home directory, a lot of config has absolute paths

grep -R <olduser> /home/<newuser>/.config/

is a good place to start.

Depending on how much stuff you have in your home directory you might find you have confused a few things by changing names.

Comment: Zanna, it's my new username only. /home/new-username
teknopaul, I did that. Currently everything is working, I will keep checking to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: teknopaul: Update, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Updated problem more.