# Lightdm low-graphics mode options not selectable

Tags: lightdm, interface

After changing my main username after [**this tips**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username/317008#comment1471505_317008), my **Lubuntu** laptop is only starting showing me only a dialog, that sais, it is in **low-graphics mode** with only one button **"OK"** and then a menu opens up with some options, but there **I cannot select other than the first option**:

```
What would you like to do?

[x] (Try running with default graphical mode)
[ ] (Reconfigure graphics)  
[ ] (Troubles boot the error)
[ ] (Exit to consol login)

                                    ([cancel] [ok])
```

I can reach cancel and "ok" with the TAB key, but I tried all combinations of TAB, arrow keys, enter, space and pg up and down to select another option than the first, but nothing worked. Also attaching a USB mouse makes no difference.

How can I reach the option "Reconfigure Graphics" ?

*Note: I am leaving this question open, although I've already recovered from this low-graphics-state (see my answer below) and there are many options [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error?noredirect=1&lq=1). It still would be interesting, how to change the selected option in that dialogue, when it seems not possible.*

Answer (score 0):

Try boot at recovery mode, low graphics, and choose"resume" option, after login, go-to settings/display and turn off every monitor not in use...

Comment: The recovery mode is not possible in the main grub selection, I had to choose "Erweiterte Optionen", there are the recovery mode kernels to start [see this manual)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Recovery-Modus/)

Comment: Anyway, This is not really an answer to the question. I asked, how I can select one of the other options (that might help me) but it is not possible to select them. that is my problem here.

Comment: I tried recovery mode and chose resume, but this didn't help. It starts with the same low-graphics mode and nothing else to do there. I also tried "failsafeX" mode

Comment: After resume, login, and settings/display and if more than one monitor, turn off monitors not in use, then restart normal... Is there only one built-in monitor, or more than one?

Comment: only one built-in monitor. And I cannot login! I just get this low-graphics box, and if i close the box, it just comes back. I cannot loginto the desktop at all

Comment: I would like to select "(Reconfigure graphics)" but I cannot klick on it, that is the problem. there is no mousepointer

Comment: The solution, in my experience, does not work with reconfigure graphics. I would install cssm and enable unity, because if no login then unity is disabled, and no other desktop is installed by default

Answer (score 0):

The solution to get rid of the low graphics warning was to install ubuntu-desktop over Lubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

When those were all installed, the Low-Graphics warning was gone, so I will never find out, how I could have reached the other options though.