# How to change default password in ubuntu preinstall image for raspi4?

Tags: raspberrypi, cloud-init

I want to change default username in raspi4 ubuntu installation.

In this image default username and password are ubuntu/ubuntu

However I want to change these default settings to something like `newname`/`0123456`(numeric only password).

How do I change user-data cloudinit file?

Note that I know numeric password is so weak, I just interested in how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make add a user using

```
sudo useradd -m <user>-G sudo
```

Replace `<user>` with the user name.
Create a password for user `<user>` using

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 <password> <salt>
```

Replace `<password>` with your desired password and in place of `<salt>`, put any random text. Change the `root/etc/shadow` file with the new password above. Delete the string between the 1st and 2nd `:` colons on the line starting with `<user>`. Paste the new value between these colons.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, but I can't help you with your Username problem.**

You can type `passwd` and then enter you're current password and then you're replacement.

For your username problem, maybe this will help? [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)