# Rename file in terminal users

Tags: command-line

```
(base) sne_jojo_g@jojoG /Users % ls
Shared      sne_jojo_g
(base) sne_jojo_g@jojoG /Users % mv sne_jojo_g jojoG 
mv: rename sne_jojo_g to jojoG: Operation not permitted
```

I want to rename the `sne_jojo_g` in `sne_jojo_g@jojoG` and also the `sne_jojo_g` file in User, how should I do it?

Comment: `/Users` indicated you may be running OS X, have you try with root ? Refer to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101328/file-cant-be-moved-by-root-on-os-x)

Comment: The `/Users/Shared` directory is certainly seen on MacOS. Are you accessing this directory via a Samba share?

Comment: What does `ls -l` show?

Answer (score 0):

- to change `prompt` in bash you, you should change the variable called `PS1` like that:

```bsh
$ PS1="[\u@\h:\w ] $ "
```

and put this var in config in `~/.bashrc` too.

- to rename your user folder and login, look [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)

```bsh
$ sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
$ sudo usermod -d /home/newHomeDir -m newUsername
```