# I want to change from root/Ubuntu to jerry/Ubuntu is that possible?

Tags: 22.04, username

I'm an Ubuntu newbie and at installation I set my computer name to "dera" and I created 2 users, "Sean" and "guest". I would like to know if it's possible to rename this from "dera" to "me". This shows up on the terminal as illustrated by the image I have attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5xMm.png).

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
 hostnamectl
```

will show what it currently is set to. This ...

```
sudo hostname me
```

is temporary and to check if this is what is wanted. This sets the hostname ("Static hostname"):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname me
```

and is permantent. No reboot required. This sets the hostname as shown to you (ie. "Pretty Hostname"):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname me --pretty
```

and is also permanent. No reboot required.

'Static hostnames": a maximum length of 64 characters and allow the use of letters, hyphens (-), underscores (_), and periods only (that is similar to the naming of URLs).

"Pretty hostnames": any valid UTF8 symbol and the maximum length you will never reach.